# data-show-toggle button size different from other button

Tags: bootstrap-table

currently Im using bootstrap-table for my mini-project.
Im trying to use the **data-show-toggle** together with **data-show-columns** and **data-search** to provide more usability.
But the data-show-toggle button is displayed slightly smaller than the other button. Is there any setting i overlooked?

Heres my table setting, js and css import. appreciate for any help given. :)

```
<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Bootstrap-Table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


<table
    id="table"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-search="true"
    data-show-toggle="true">
....
</table>
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlHqm.png)

Comment: Created a jsFiddle, but there isn't a problem what you said: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/3436/.

Comment: for unknown reason, the data-show-toggle button simply refuse to display properly even though i replicate your code and import the same css and js file. Do you mind take a look at the code, thanks. http://justpaste.it/ongi

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a regular way to change toggle button size and fix this issue, neither the reason. That's why I decided to change the javascript file directly(also I needed to translate some texts). I would not recommend this way because it is not proper use.